# How to do web scraping python com with span class?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I'm trying to get date and time of update from this page.

How I can get date and time from last update?

Anybody can help me resolve this?

```
    import requests 
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import datetime
    import re
    import platform
    import time
    import urllib3
    urllib3.disable_warnings()
    
    start_time = time.time()
    url = 'https://www.tesourodireto.com.br/titulos/precos-e-taxas.htm'
    r = requests.get(url, verify=False)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    now = now.strftime('%A, %B %d, %Y  %I:%M %p')
    
    r_html = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r_html, "html.parser")
    
    all = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"td-mercado-update"})
    all


**[<div class="td-mercado-update">
     <p class="td-mercado-text td-mercado-text--mobile">Última atualização:
                    <span class="td-mercado-text--bold td-mercado-text--bold--mobile"></span>
     </p>
     </div>]**

    
    print( soup.find("span", class_="td-mercado-text--bold td-mercado-text--bold--mobile")\["Última atualização:"\])
```

**> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call

> last)
>  in 
> ----> 1 print( soup.find("span", class_="td-mercado-text--bold td-mercado-text--bold--mobile")["Última atualização:"])
>
> ```
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py in __getitem__(self, key)
>    1404         """tag[key] returns the value of the 'key' attribute for the Tag,
>    1405         and throws an exception if it's not there."""
> -> 1406         return self.attrs[key]
>    1407 
>    1408     def __iter__(self):
>
> KeyError: 'Última atualização:'**
> ```

Comment: The data is loaded using javascript. `requests` does not execute javascript.

Comment: Thanks @JustinEzequiel for your information. 
I have a dout: How I can identify this and how I can resolve this?
I thought that every webscrapin was in html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to access the source code of that web page you could directly get data from the API that web page uses to fetch data and get it in your desired format see the below code and needed to use `verify=False` due to an HTTPS error on that website.

```
import requests
data=requests.get("https://www.tesourodireto.com.br/json/br/com/b3/tesourodireto/service/api/treasurybondsinfo.json",verify=False).json()
T=data["response"]["TrsrBondMkt"]["qtnDtTm"].split("T")
date=T[0].split("-")
hour=T[1][0:5].replace(":","h")
print(f"{date[2]}/{date[1]}/{date[0]} • {hour}min")
```

Output
[image: Output]
Let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: Good. Excellent!
How I can know that  is not necessary acess source code and how i can see api in this page. Thanks a lot

Comment: Before loading the website in the browser open inspect element and go to the Network tab to see if the data is coming from any other request(API) than the main page or is it already parsed in the HTML received in the first request. Better Approach to see those requests would be via Tools like fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to 'span' element, then replace 'div' with 'span'.
   This will give you all the avialable span element.

```py
   all = soup.findALl("span")
```

2. To search for the specific attribute in span, for ex: 'class'

```py
   all = soup.findAll("span", {"class":"<class-name>"})
```